# Is it safe to print an unsigned char with the %u specifier via the printf function?

Tags: c++, printf

So, I realize that `%u` is for printing an `unsigned int`.  And `unsigned int` is usually more than a single byte (typically 32 bits/4 bytes I think) on most systems.  `unsigned char` is always one byte.  So, is it safe to use the `%u` format specifier to print a byte as a number?  Will type promotion kick in?  Or does the variadic argument list muck things up?  Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char val = 'A';
    printf("%u", val);  // is this safe?
}
```

Assuming an ASCII encoding, the output should be `65`.  However, as `%u` is technically for `unsigned int` rather than `unsigned char`, I'm curious if there are there cases where I would get bytes of garbage, or access the stack in an unexpected way.

Comment: You'd use %hhu for an unsigned char. Or you could cast your unsigned char to an unsigned int and use %u. I suspect that what you have might happen to work, but it's not good practice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `printf()` is a C function; if the calling code is C++, which is the appropriate tag to use?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The language the code is being compiled as

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: The C++ standard incorporates some version of the C standard by reference, or parts of it at least, but it may then specify its own rules that alter the things it takes from C. So `printf` is not “a C function.” When using C, `printf` should conform to the rules of the C standard (or other C specification being used), and the call to it will use C rules. When using C++, `printf` should conform to the rules of the C++ standard (or other C++ specification). The languages have diverged and continue to diverge more.

Comment: I tagged it as both as I write code in both, and this behaviour seemed likely to be the same in both as printf is fairly consistent from my understanding and it seemed silly to ask the exact same question twice with different tags.  If I had to pick one though it would be c++ as most of our code has been converted to c++, but I still use some c code for a handful of low level and legacy programs.

Comment: In my opinion, C++ is better than C for low level programming (granted, some effort to avoid C++ features that might be inappropriate for low level programming in C++, e.g. I/O streams facilities, or RTTI facilities, or try/catch exceptions for flow control **cough**).  For legacy programs... they are what they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%u` expects an `unsigned int`, so you will have to cast the `unsigned char` when passing it to `%u`, eg:

```c
printf( "%u", (unsigned int) val );
```

It is *likely* that when passing the `unsigned char` as-is, it gets *promoted* to the size of the `unsigned int` when pushed onto the call stack, in which case `%u` *may* work without casting, but you should not rely on that behavior.  Jut pass the correct type to begin with.

Alternatively, you can use `%hhu` instead (C99+), which expects an `unsigned char`, eg:

```c
printf( "%hhu", val );
```

Comment: Re "*It is likely that when passing the unsigned char as-is, it gets promoted to the size of the unsigned int*", It gets promoted to an `int` or an `unsigned int`, guaranteed. And aren't `unsigned int` and `int` guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: It has been canon in Stack Overflow that an `unsigned char` needs to be cast to `unsigned int` to get guaranteed behavior when used with `%u`. But C 2018 6.3.1.1 says “The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may be used: — An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`…” And an `val` is an object with an integer type whose conversion rank is less than `int` and `unsigned int`, and an `unsigned int` can be used there.

Comment: Note the answer is now tagged c++ while the answer and comments reference the C standard.

Comment: It is not just likely, it is required (by all standard versions of both C and C++).